# Bash script fails in DD-wrt

Tags: bash, shell-script, dd-wrt

I have the following bash script running at startup on my WRT1900ac linksys:

```
USER="admin"
PASS="passhere"
PROTOCOL="http"
ROUTER_IP="192.168.1.1"

# Port to connect to which will provide the JSON data.
PORT=9898

while [ 1 ]
do
    # Grab connected device MAC addresses through router status page.
    MACS=$(curl -s --user $USER:$PASS $PROTOCOL://$ROUTER_IP/Status_Wireless.live.asp)

    # clear temp JSON file
    echo > temp.log

    # Get hostname and IP (just in case there is no hostname).
    for MAC in $(echo $MACS | grep -oE "wl_mac::[a-z0-9]{2}:[a-z0-9]{2}:[a-z0-9]{2}:[a-z0-9]{2}:[a-z0-9]{2}:[a-z0-9]{2}" | cut -c 9-);
    do
        grep 0x /proc/net/arp | awk '{print $1 " " $4}' | while IFS= read -r line
        do
        IP=$(echo $line | cut -d' ' -f1)
        MACTEMP=$(echo $line | cut -d' ' -f2)
        HOST=$(arp -a | grep $IP | cut -d' ' -f1)

        # if no hostname exists, just use IP.
        if [ "$HOST" == "" ]
        then
            HOST=$IP
        fi

        if [ "$MAC" == "$MACTEMP" ]
        then
            JSON="{'hostname' : '$HOST', 'mac_address' : '$MAC'}"
            echo $JSON >> temp.log
        fi

        done
    done

    # Provide the JSON formatted output on $PORT of router.
    # This allows one connection before closing the port (connect, receive data, close).
    # Port will reopen every 5 minutes with new data as setup in a cron job.
    echo -e "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n\n $(cat temp.log)" | nc -l -p$PORT >/dev/null

    # Wait for 10 seconds and do it all over.
    sleep 10

done
```

And for some reason when I reboot the router and then try to visit `http://192.168.1.1:9898` it just shows a blank page even though I have my android cell phone connected via wifi to the router and the router shows the MAC address on the status page.

What *should* be on that page is all the wireless MAC address that are currently connected to the router and displaying them out in JSON form.

Answer (score 1):

What you posted is not a *bash* script, it's a script that will be executed by some unspecified shell. A shell script should always begin with a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) line. A bash script must begin with `#!/usr/bin/env bash` or `#!` followed by the path to bash on your system, typically `#!/bin/bash`.

I haven't looked at your script in detail, but chances are that it's failing because you use bash constructs but embedded Linux installations such as DD-wrt don't typically include bash, only BusyBox ash. To make your script work on DD-wrt, stick to portable sh constructs. You can use [checkbashisms](https://sourceforge.net/projects/checkbaskisms/) (available in most Linux distributions) to look for bash-specific constructs.

One bash-specific construct I've spotted is the `==` operator in conditionals, e.g. `[ "$HOST" == "" ]`. The portable way to write this is `[ "$HOST" = "" ]` or `[ -z "$HOST" ]`. Likewise `[ "$MAC" = "$MACTEMP" ]`.

Also [always put double quotes around variable substitutions unless you know why you need to leave them out](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters). Your script may happen to work if your data never contains shell special characters, but don't count on luck, just type those `"`.